useEffect only triggers server action if additional server action is called
I'm using a NextJS with a client component that calls a server action in useEffect. However, randomly it stopped working and the only fix is to call and additional server action. For what it's worth, I'm also using a NextUI Table component later on to display the data but I don't think that's a part of this issue.
const [retrievedJobs, setRetrievedJobs] = useState<Job[] | undefined>([]);
const [retrievedProblems, setRetrievedProblems] = useState<Problem[] | undefined>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getJobs = async () => {
    const jobs = await fetchAllJobs();
    console.log("getJobs:jobs: ", jobs)
    setRetrievedJobs(jobs)
  }

  const getProblems = async () => {
    const problems = await fetchAllProblems();
    setRetrievedProblems(problems)
  }

  getJobs();
  getProblems();
}, [])

Here is my server action code. This works when running locally and I have other server actions which use the exact same code but with a different query that do work. I've tested the query as well and it should be working.
export async function fetchAllJobs(): Promise<Job[]> {
  let jobs: Job[] = []
  
  try {
    neo4jDriver = await newNeo4jDriver();
    const session = neo4jDriver.session({ database: 'neo4j' });
    
    const result = await session.executeRead(async (tx: any) => {
      return await tx.run(`
        MATCH (j:Job) RETURN j
        ORDER BY j.title
      `)
    })

    result.records.map((record: any) => {
      jobs.push({
        id: record.get(0).properties.id,
        title: record.get(0).properties.title
      })
    })
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  return jobs // I've tried with finally as well, doesn't work either.
}

With this code console.log("getJobs:jobs: ", jobs) will print out the jobs as expected, but if I remove getProblems it will no longer work... What's going on?

Check fetchAllProblems() method must return data and use Try and catch it's help to find error

I just made edits to include the server action code
